# Custom Code Snippets not showing up in intellisense in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am trying to add a custom code snippets for typescript react. But after adding it, it is not showing in intellisense or in Insert Snippet command window. I performed below steps:

1. Creating the code snippet. File > Preferences > User Snippets > Typescript React. My json:

   ```
   "React Component": {
       "prefix": "myreactc",
       "body": [
           "import * as React from "react";"
       ],
       "description": "Adds a react component."
   }
   ```
2. Updated following setting:

   "editor.tabCompletion": true
3. Create a new blank TSX file and type: "myreactc" but nothing shows up in intellisense.

I have also restarted visual studio code, but no luck.

Visual Studio Code Details:

Version 1.14.2

Commit cb82febafda0c8c199b9201ad274e25d9a76874e

Date 2017-07-19T23:34:09.706Z

Shell 1.6.6

Renderer 56.0.2924.87

Node 7.4.0

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the code was commented :) The default template has the code commented, i updated the code but forgot to uncomment the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was stupidly changing the snippet name and not the snippet prefix

```
"For Loop": {
    "prefix": "my name for intellisense",
    "body": [
```